# angularjs - ui-route - how to attach mutlple URL with same name?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app, I require to attach multiple `url` with same `state` - how do i achieve this?

here is my existing state:

```
.state('createCase', {
        url: '/createCase',
        templateUrl: null,
        controller: null,
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        },
```

also I would like to attache another `url` as like this:

```
.state('createCase', {
        url: '/createCase?sn=12345', //(12345 is dynamic )
        templateUrl: null,
        controller: null,
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        },
```

here is my current function:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: function(){ 
          console.log('from 1oauth'); 
          return 'app/login/login.html';
        },
        controller: 'loginCtrl as ctrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
      })
      .state('oauth', {
        url: '/oauth',
        templateUrl: function(){

          console.log('from 2oauth');
          return 'app/oauth/oauth.template.html';

        },
        controller: 'OAuthController as ctrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
      })
      .state('createCase', {
        url: '/createCase',
        templateUrl: null,
        controller: null,
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }

        }
      })


    // if (isWeb()){  
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });
    // }

    // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define two different states for same url. In your controller, you can use `$state.params` object that has query parameters as properties.

Your route

```
.state('createCase', {
        url: '/createCase',
        templateUrl: null,
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        },
        params: {
          sn: null
        }
```

Your controller

```
function MyCtrl($state) {
    console.log($state.params);
}
```

Comment: at present I URL is : `http://localhost:3000/createCase?sn=12345` But when I console like you, I am getting empty object. -

Comment: @user2024080 sorry I'm new to ui-router :-) I just updated the route. Notice I defined the parameters we accept in the route and added a default value for sn parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Define in your **route**:

```
.state('createCase', {
        url: '/createCase?sn',   // bind your query param to URL
        templateUrl: null,
        controller: null,
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        },
```

In your **controller**,
inject `$stateParams` to dependencies and use it with `$stateParams.sn` whatever you need.

Example:

```
$state.go('createCase', {sn:1234});  // move to state with a param

$stateParams.sn   // get a value of ==> 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create a parent state and sub states. If you just want to have access to `$routeParams` you can can pass them to the controller or leave them out when using same state.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('createCase', {
                url: '/createCase',
                template: '<h3>Create Case</h3><div ui-view="detail"></div>'
            })
            .state('createCase.detail', {
                parent: 'createCase',
                url: '/:sn',
                views: {  'detail@createCase': {
                        template: '{{sn}}',
                        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
                            $scope.sn = $stateParams.sn;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="createCase">createCase</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="createCase.detail({sn:'123456'})">createCaseDetail 123456</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="createCase.detail({sn:''})">createCaseDetail None</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```